# Is it possible to add Std.Dev to the JMeter Ant HTML Report

Tags: ant, jmeter

I would like to get Std.Dev in the JMeter Ant  Task HTML Report.How do I do that?

I tried to modify and add    in the jmeter-results-deatil-report_21.xsl , but thrown below error

BUILD FAILED
D:\JMETER\apache-jmeter-2.13\apache-jmeter-2.13\extras\build.xml:139: Fatal error during transformation using D:\JMETER\apache-jmeter-2.13\apache-jmeter-2.13\extras\jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl: Fatal error during transformation using D:\JMETER\apache-jmeter-2.13\apache-jmeter-2.13\extras\jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl: Could not find function: Math.sqrt; Line#: 174; Column#: 97

Please guide me!

[image]

Thanks,
Rajani

Comment: It is possible. I was able to include throughput in the report. I never tried sqrt. Did u check this - http://www.edankert.com/transforms/xslt.invoke-java.html ?

Comment: Alternative way to do square root in xslt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12743828/how-to-do-square-root-in-xslt-1-0